# Is Zend_View_Helper_Cycle efficient?

Tags: zend-framework, helper, zend-view

I am creating a table with zebra style in my view:-

```
$sr_no = 1;
if($sr_no % 2 == 0){
  $style = 'class="even-row"';
    }else{
          $style = 'class="odd-row"';
         }
    <tr <?php echo $style?>>
    $sr_no++;
```

Zend Framework provides this

```
echo $this->cycle(array("class='even-row'","class='odd-row'"))->next();
```

However, I think, behind the scenes it is doing the same as my code. So which one is Optimised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends on your use case doesn't it? Your code will work in very simple cases, but Zend_View_Helper_Cycle can cope with more complex requirements. See the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.cycle).

A quick comparison of your code with the code of [Zend_View_Helper_Cycle](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/View/Helper/Cycle.php) will tell you that you are trying to compare very different animals.

Whether it is efficient or not depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need support for legacy browsers, you can achieve zebra style with CSS

```css
#mytable tr:nth-child(odd) { background: red }
```